# Pandas: Merging multiple (~30) tables together?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I currently have 30+ individual tables in a folder that are in this format:

Name1 = pd.read_csv('Name1.txt')

Name1:

```
         A    B    C    D    
type1    1    1    NaN  4
type2    2    0    NaN  2
type3    3    2.1  NaN  .2
type4    1    2    NaN  1
```

So I have like 30 such tables and would like to get a complete table that looks something like this:

```
       Name1/A  Name1/B Name1/D  Name2/A Name2/B Name2/C ...... Name30/C 
type1    1        1       4       ...     ...     ...             ...         
type2    2        0       2       ...     ...     ...             ...
type3    3        2.1     .2      ...     ...     ...             ...
type4    1        2       1       ...     ...     ...             ...
```

I have been attempting to use a for loop to read in the data and use pd.concat(...) but it doesn't seem to be doing anything

I suppose one of my main issues is figuring out how I am suppose to create a dataframe that combines all these different charts without having to do pd.read_csv('NameX.txt')  for ALL 30 tables and then merging them all together.
I assume for loops would be the main savior for this, but everytime I try to read them in a for-loop, it tells me the file can't be found.

Also if it helps, my files are named in such "Name1.txt", "Name2.txt", "Name3.txt"...and so on, also the type1 to type4 column doesn't change throughout each chart and the columns with values NaN are meant to be removed in the final, larger table.

Any suggestions would be amazing! Thanks you!

Comment: Does [pandas Panel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel) works for you?

Comment: Yes! I believe I have pandas.Panel! Do you have any ideas?

Comment: For your comment below, it seems that you want everything in **one** DataFrame. The Panel would give you severals DataFrames.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
names = ['Name{}'.format(i) for i in xrange(1, 31)]
files = ['{}.txt'.format(n) for n in names]

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0) for f in files],
               axis=1, keys=names)

cols = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns = cols.str.get(0).astype(str) + '/' + cols.str.get(1)

df.iloc[:, :10]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried this and have been trying to change it a little bit because this is giving me one column with everything all together in this one column, making the data extremely messy and compound. I am glad that now everything seems to be in one dataframe, but now am trying to manipulate it into various columns.

Comment: @CallieJester the `axis=1` parameter should ensure the dataframe returned by each `pd.read_csv` is concatenated side by side.  Can you show the actual code you are running?  Or the output you are getting?

Comment: My code is nearly identical to the one you suggested. The only difference is that I put names in a name list. The output for the columns is like:
Name1.ABCDABCDABC ext...

Comment: @CallieJester I've updated my post.  Notice I inserted `index_col=0` into the `read_csv` call.

Comment: Wow, this is really strange, I see what you did, but when I am trying this, it gives me 0 columns now and a number of rows that have all the numbers next to eachother like: NaN/t0.00/1.00/NaN....

Answer (score 1):

If you do not whish everything in just one DataFrame you can try [Pandas Panel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html)

```
dfs = {n:pd.read_csv('Name{}.txt'.format(n) for n in range(1,30)}
panel = pd.Panel(dfs)
```

For more information, you can check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel).